# Multiple select with jquery dilemma

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown that allows users to choose certain options. After which it calls a php script for processing. The problem I have is that if I choose only one option, everything works fine, but when I choose more then one option, it doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<select name="select[]" id="the_select">
<option></option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var form_data = {
    select : $("#the_select").val()
};
```

Now my php script expects an array, how can I accomplish this? Do I have to loop through the select element in javascript and build an array to send?

Comment: what doesn't work? What error do you get? or What unexpected behaviors occurs?

Comment: i think serialize form will work

Answer (score 1):

Use `serialize()` method to serialize the whole form with one function and let jQuery do the array management and heavy lifting of encoding variables

```
var ajaxData=$('#myForm').serialize()
$.post( url, ajaxData, function(){
  /* ajax success code*/

})
```

API refrence: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Excellent answer; however the serialize function does not work when using arrays within the name

Comment: @Darwayne no idea what you are talking about, have never had any problem serializing complex forms with it, including multi selects

Comment: whenever you have multiple form elements with the same element like so 

    "<input name='age[]' />"
 It creates an array in php, however when using the serialize function you will only get one element instead of all elements

Comment: @Darwayne works fine here, and have never had that problem you mention. I do a ton of ajax also  http://jsfiddle.net/QRQJT/

Comment: wow that does work, not sure why it never worked for me. Thanx for the educational response

Comment: @Darwayne  perhaps it is best to test your theory before suggesting it doesn't work. The serialize function has been around for years... yours is not the only form with "[]" in names

Answer (score 0):

Does each  element have a unique id=""? If not, this is likely the reason it's not working. Alternatively, you could use class="the_select", because classes do not need to be unique. The jQuery would need to change to:

```
var form_data = {
    select : $(".the_select").val()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a multi select make sure you include the multiple attribute:

```
<select name="select[]" id="the_select" multiple>
<option></option>
</select>
```

If you are using more than one select and your are trying to get all of their values, then you will need to select each one individually like so:

```
$('select[name="select[]"]').each(function(){
// Do Something with the value here
$(this).val()
});
```